# Bootstrap jquery long press with sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add a long click to a sortable group of responsive bootstrap buttons. The only way the longclick function seems to trigger is if I put it on the #list_content container. However, then $this doesn't refer to the actual button div (.sm-col-4) that triggered the event.

```
$('#list_content').mayTriggerLongClicks().on('longClick', function() {
    alert("long_click=" + JSON.stringify($(this)));
});
```

Hoping that someone has some ideas on how I can get the colid that triggered the event, and as well to prevent the long-press from triggering when the user is moving the button.

https://jsfiddle.net/7yhkp9eo/3/

Edit for answer #1.

Thanks for the response. Interesting, that works in the fiddle but not in my app. When I set the selector to:

```
$('#list_content')
```

I see the longClick event listener on the button as div#list_content.ui-sortable for both click and mousedown. When I set the selector to

```
$('a.btn')
```

there is no event listener for click or mousedown according to chrome developer tools.  I also have this code in the main $(document).ready() section in my app.

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function (e) {
    if($(e.target).hasClass('popover-content')) {
        fp_popover_close = false;
    } else
        fp_popover_close = true; 
});
```

Which I need to get a slider control in a popover to work properly. I see that event on the button with $('a.btn') but not the long click.

Answer (score 0):

About the colid and the trigger of the event, in your fiddle this is working for me...

```
$('a.btn').mayTriggerLongClicks().on('longClick', function() {
    var colId = $(this).parent('div').attr('colid');
    alert(colId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't solve this through the right selector at the sortable stage, I was able to add the long click event when the button was originally created by the application and then it only fires if sortable is active.